# Why is seperation vector intgrated when electic field is calculated from charge distribution?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

As for as I know the formula to derive electric field from charge distribution(volume) is given by:

$\vec{E} = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0  } \int{ \frac { \rho(x,y,z)  \hat{r} \vec{dV}}{r^2} }$

where $dV = dx dy dz $

but for a given charge:
$\vec{E} = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{q }{r^2} \hat{r} $

It makes sense that q = $\int \rho \vec{dV} $

But why is $ r^2 $ integrated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small amount of charge, $dq$, will create an electric field at everyp point in space.

That small charge can be part of a continuous distribution, $dq=\rho dV$.

So, that small charge will create a small electric field:

$$d\vec{E}(\vec{r})=K \cdot \frac{dq}{r^2} \hat{r}$$

Where $K$ is obviously $\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}$

The distance $\vec{r}$ is the distance from the charge $dq$ to the point where you want to calculate the electric field.

Now, if, instead of having one small charge, $dq$, you have thousands (a whole continuous medium), then you have to sum up all contributions, that is

$$\vec{E}=\iiint d\vec{E} = \iiint K \frac{dq}{r^2} \hat{r} $$

And the radius $\vec{r}$ is varying, not because you move, but because you're accounting for all $dq$ out there. In other words, the point $P$ in where you calculate the electric field remains the same. But the position of every $dq$ is different, so the distance varies.

An example: imagine you want to calculate the electric field due to a charged cylinder, on a point $P$ above its axis. The electric field in the point $P$ is the sum of all contributions. Each charge in the cylinder is creating a small electric field on $P$. The total electric field on $P$ is the sum (integral) of all fields.

The point P remains constasnt, but the charges are in different positions. Near charges will create stronger fields on $P$ that those which are farther away. That's why the distance matters. The distance varies in every $dq$